# Way to mount a small tv (27-32”) on bottoms of stairs angled down slightly?

Tags: electrical, walls, television

I’m looking to add a tv to underside of stairs? Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, yes it is possible. We can not tell you how because we do not what the Underside of your stairs looks like or how it is constructed.  Add much more details to get an informed answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean anything remotely like a "modern" TV, (flat panel with VESA mounting holes on the back) it's trivial - just screw a "ceiling mount" to the bottom of the stairs. Get one which allows for an angle adjustment - most do.

Comment: Will look into that! Thanks!